# Connect local IPython notebook to Spark on air gapped cluster

Tags: python-2.7, hadoop, jupyter-notebook, putty, pyspark

I have a W7 machine that I use for my daily work. My company also has an air gapped Hadoop cluster on a private cloud. I can only access the cloud through putty.
When I want to use Spark on the cluster I launch putty, and then do one of these two things:

- Just launch pyspark from shell
- Use VNC to access a RedHat GUI on the cluster and launch IPython notebook in Spark mode from there

Is there a way to use my local W7 IPython notebook to connect to Spark?

---

EDIT FOLLOWING SOME TRIAL AND ERROR AFTER Daniel Darabos comment

I installed Spark locally on my W7 machine following [this tutorial](http://ysinjab.com/2015/03/28/hello-spark/).
I then created a new pyspark profile and changed the startup file following [this tutorial](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/08/how-to-use-ipython-notebook-with-apache-spark/).
At this point I can start Ipython locally and successfully have it create a spark context.
When I run:

```
sc.stop()
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('SPark Test').setMaster('localhost:7077')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

I then get an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-1e8f5b112924> in <module>()
      1 sc.stop()
      2 conf = SparkConf().setAppName('SPark Test').setMaster('localhost:7077')
----> 3 sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

C:\Spark\python\pyspark\context.pyc in __init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls)
    111         try:
    112             self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,
--> 113                           conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
    114         except:
    115             # If an error occurs, clean up in order to allow future SparkContext creation:

C:\Spark\python\pyspark\context.pyc in _do_init(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
    168 
    169         # Create the Java SparkContext through Py4J
--> 170         self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
    171 
    172         # Create a single Accumulator in Java that we'll send all our updates through;

C:\Spark\python\pyspark\context.pyc in _initialize_context(self, jconf)
    222         Initialize SparkContext in function to allow subclass specific initialization
    223         """
--> 224         return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)
    225 
    226     @classmethod

C:\Spark\python\lib\py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
    699         answer = self._gateway_client.send_command(command)
    700         return_value = get_return_value(answer, self._gateway_client, None,
--> 701                 self._fqn)
    702 
    703         for temp_arg in temp_args:

C:\Spark\python\pyspark\sql\utils.pyc in deco(*a, **kw)
     34     def deco(*a, **kw):
     35         try:
---> 36             return f(*a, **kw)
     37         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     38             s = e.java_exception.toString()

C:\Spark\python\lib\py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    298                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    299                     'An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n'.
--> 300                     format(target_id, '.', name), value)
    301             else:
    302                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not parse Master URL: 'localhost:7077'
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$createTaskScheduler(SparkContext.scala:2693)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:506)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:234)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:214)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:68)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an SSH tunnel with PuTTY that forwards a local port (e.g. `7077`) to the Spark master (e.g. `spark-master:7077`). Then in your local IPython Notebook use the local port (`spark://localhost:7077`) as the Spark master's address.

Comment: Thanks. I have create a tunnel in PuTTY to server_name:4040 and followed a tutorial to install spark on W7. I must be doing something wrong because I can connect to the local Spark but not to the cluster. See edits to my question.

Comment: You need `spark://localhost:7077`, not just `localhost:7077`. I've edited my answer to make this clear.